# How to show paths in Google Earth on mouse-over?

Tags: google-earth

I've seen that paths included in a kml file can be configured to show up only when you do a mouse-over:
http://www.barnabu.co.uk/flight-route-maps-for-australia-and-new-zealand/

How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out myself. You have to name a `StyleMap` specifying a normal and highlighted state. Then make a `Placemark` use that `StyleMap`.

```
<Style id="sh_spider">
    <IconStyle>
        <scale>1.0</scale>
        <Icon><href>/Users/You/Icon.png</href></Icon>
    </IconStyle>
    <LabelStyle>
        <color>ffffffff</color>
        <scale>1.4</scale>
    </LabelStyle>
    <BalloonStyle>
        <text>&#36;&#91;description&#93;</text>
    </BalloonStyle>
    <LineStyle>
        <color>ffff8a6d</color>
        <width>4.4</width>
    </LineStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="sn_spider">
    <IconStyle>
        <scale>0.5</scale>
        <Icon><href>/Users/You/Icon.png</href></Icon>
    </IconStyle>
    <LabelStyle>
        <color>ffe5e5e5</color>
        <scale>0.9</scale>
    </LabelStyle>
    <BalloonStyle>
        <text>&#36;&#91;description&#93;</text>
    </BalloonStyle>
    <LineStyle>
        <color>00ff8a6d</color>
        <width>4.4</width>
    </LineStyle>
</Style>
<StyleMap id="spider"><Pair><key>normal</key><styleUrl>#sn_spider</styleUrl></Pair><Pair><key>highlight</key><styleUrl>#sh_spider</styleUrl></Pair></StyleMap>
```